# Coredata Modeling

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I just started to look into core data recently and was wondering if I was modeling my data model correctly.

I am creating a trip planning app and created two entities, Trip and Day

Trip entity has attributes - name of trip, location of trip, duration

Day entity has attributes - day_num(if it's day 1 or 2 and so on), breakfast, lunch, dinner, shopping, attraction

So basically each attribute in my 'Day' entity (except for the day_num attribute) is going to be an array of items and the relationship from trip to day would be one to many.

So my question is,

1. I was wondering if I should seperate each attribute in my 'Day' entity as a seperate entity instead of having them as attributes of array types.

So my new model would be

trip -> day

and day would have a one to many relationship with,

Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Shopping, Attraction entities.

2. If i do seperate my 'Day' entity's attributes into entities, do I need some form of 'foreign key' to relate between entities? (e.g. Breakfast entity should have a day_num attribute to specify which day I am referring to or my Day entity needs a trip_id attribute to know which trip i'm talking about.)

I will try to elaborate better if my question is misleading in any way.

Thank you!

Comment: The neat thing about Core Data is that you can use object oriented concepts for your data model.

I keep thinking you could have an Event entity, and the Day could contain a one to many relationship to Event. Event is something that happens in a day, and can have a start and end time a location, transportation details etc. 

And then you can subclass Event: Meal, Shopping, Attraction. If you find it useful, you could further subclass Meal into Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Cocktails.

Comment: Also, Core Data automatically gives you a relationship back to the parent object. I.e. Event will have a relationship back to its owning Day, Day will have a relationship back to its Trip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I have a Day entity with num_day = 1, how do I know which trip it's referring to without having a foreign key like normal relational database?

Comment: Core Data let's you specify an inverse relationship. For instance, your Trip entity can have a one to many relationship called `days`, which will be, at runtime, a Set<Day> value type. And you can specify the inverse relationship `trip` which at runtime will be a Trip object. So if you have a day, `let theDay = blah blah`, you can get the Trip it belongs to simply as `let theTrip = theDay.trip` Core Data will manage the relationships for you.